# Rails: Unable to access log file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, capistrano, mongrel

I get the following error when restarting my rails app. I've had this problem before, on another server with another app, but can't remember what the problem was, or how I solved it.

```
Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /apps/staging/releases/20090310162127/log/staging.log exists and is chmod 0666. The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.
```

I'm deploying to a mongrel cluster with capistrano on Ubuntu.

When I do `ls -l /apps/staging/releases/20090310162127/log/staging.log`

the result is:

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 me grp 51 Mar 10 16:07 /apps/staging/releases/20090310162127/log/staging.log
```

The log dir is a `link` to /apps/staging/shared/log.

What's going on?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It turned out to be a subtle rails bug:

When an exception is raised in these two lines

```
logger = ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new(configuration.log_path)
logger.level = ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.const_get(configuration.log_level.to_s.upcase)
```

rails assumes it can't find the log file. However, the actual error occurred in the second line: a NameError because the constant is incorrect. The reason is that there was a legacy log level in my configuration file:

```
config.log_level = Logger::INFO
```

Rails 2.2 uses its own logger, and doesn't understand the above line.

Solution: remove line, or use:

```
config.log_level = :info
```

Comment: Good to know. I think I've come across this issue myself a few times.

Comment: I ran into this when I switched my mailer and logger commands:
 config.log_level = :sendmail
D'oh!

Comment: Thanks for this, kept thinking it was a VirtualBox bug.

Comment: I was getting a similar error without the second error.  Turned out `cap deploy` was creating `share\log` as root, and rails couldn't make the log file.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the most misleading error message ever. Thanks for figuring out.

Answer (score 0):

Is Rails running as `me`?  If not, what user is it running as?  Is that user `jail`'ed?  Does the user have traverse permissions for all components of `/apps/staging/shared/log` as well as all components of `/apps/staging/releases/20090310162127/log`?

Comment: Yes, it's running as "me", no idea what jail'ed means though. Yes, all the dir components are traversable. releases/20090310162127 is probably accessed through a link (called current).

Comment: @Michiel, jailed means that / is remapped to a special directory for security reasons.  Can you confirm that if you 'su - me' and 'touch /apps/staging/releases/20090310162127/log/staging.log' you do not get an error, correct?

Comment: Interesting - I should look into that. The error message was completely misleading though - nothing to do with the log file.