# Rails 3.2.6: Getting 'Unable to access log file' error for development.log file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, ruby-on-rails-3.2, railscasts

This seems like it would be a common problem, but I just can't seem to find the solution through google searches, etc.

I just created a new Rails 3.2.6 application and configured it to use the PostgreSQL database for my local development.  I followed this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql) and was able to get everything installed and set up correctly.

However, whenever I try to do any rails generate or rake commands (`rails generate model`, `rake db:migrate` etc), I get the following error referring to my `development.log` file:

```
Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /Users/****/projects/rails_projects/rails_app/log/development.log exists and is chmod 0666. The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.
```

I see these other stackoverflow questions/answers, but they don't fit my case exactly:

- [Rails: Unable to access log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632592/rails-unable-to-access-log-file) <- This is back in the days of Rails 2.2
- [Ruby on Rails Setup: Unable to access log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929919/ruby-on-rails-setup-unable-to-access-log-file) <- This is regarding a production environment using Apache.  I am on a local development environment.

Other than that error, my application runs fine.  Also, if I create a new rails application with all its defaults, I don't get this error.

Any suggestions/hints would be much appreciated.  Or if you need any more information about my local environment, please let me know.

Comment: That file is not part of Postgres (at least not a standard installation). So I don't think it's a Postgres problemn

Comment: Yea, I figured... It's just that the only thing I did differently was use PostgreSQL for my db for my local development environment, and that is when I started getting the errors.  If I just use the Rails defaults for local development (i.e. SQLite, etc), I do not get this error.  Let me re-word/edit the question and re-post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I basically did what the error message suggested and did a `chmod 0666` on the `development.log` file:

```
$> cd /Users/****/projects/rails_projects/rails_app/log/  
$> chmod 0666 development.log
```

Everything worked fine after that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that the log file is there and that you can access it? I've done some similar things in the past.

Comment: Hi @BServiss, thanks for your response.  Yes, the file always existed and I was always able to access it.  I actually just went ahead and manually did a chmod on the file, and I'm no longer receiving the error now.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out with `sudo` if your enviroment its on linux, for example, i got that error trying to run the migration - `rake db:migrate`, so i used `sudo rake db:migrate` and that's work, maybe because the rake when its trying to consult development.log doesn't have the right permissions or something like that.