# Rails Error: Unable to access log file And ActionView::Template::Error Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano, passenger

I'm deploy my app with capistrano on centos (apache + passenger), when access my web I got `HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error)' and check error_log file , here's error look likes  :

```
DAV/2 Phusion_Passenger/3.0.19 mod_ssl/2.2.24 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /home/admin/myaap/releases/20130506191509/log/production.log exists and is chmod 0666. The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed..
```

production.log permission

`-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 46211 May  6 20:49 production.log`

and

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Permission denied - /home/admin/myaap/releases/20130506191509/tmp/cache/assets/D3B
```

directory D3B not found.

I am looking for a solution via google, one of which is `sudo chown -R root:root /home/admin/myapp/` but not working for me, Is there any other way to fix it?

Note :

I'm using user root for deploy and installing rvm, and directory root location on user 'admin' (kloxo control panel)

UPDATE

On error_log file not found error about permission and unable to access, I'm using `chmod go-w /home/admin/myapp` and `chmod 0666 production.log` , but my web still 500 server error, How do I check error?

Comment: I got my tmp folder like this `drwxrwxr-x 3 ubuntu ubuntu` (permissions, user, group) and is working, maybe you can guide from these permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Rails is suggesting in the error log, you should change permissions for the log file to 066:

```
chmod 0666 production.log
```

You are using root to deploy, but the web server is using another user name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your apache user the owner of your app like:

```
sudo chown -R apacheuser:apacheuser /home/admin/myapp/
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always had success with the the log file permissions as 644.  When this has happened to me, more than once I might add, it has always been answered by the question linked below.  Since this is the first answer in Google for the query I use, I'm linking to the answer that I really want.

[Rails: Unable to access log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632592/rails-unable-to-access-log-file)