# Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /home.../log/development.log exists and is chmod 0666

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-migration

Im trying to migrate a `db2` database to Ruby on Rails, but just when I run `rails g scaffold`, I get this:

`Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /home/.../log/development.log exists and is chmod 0666. The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.`

I have checked and my `development.log` does not exist! I'm not sure why, since I followed every step during the installation, but still my file doesn't exist. How can I create it? I have already tried uninstalling and installing Rails again, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Maybe just do what it asks you to do?:

```
$ touch the_required_path/development.log
$ chmod 0666  the_required_path/development.log
```

Comment: Bummer… yeap, that was it. Im sorry and thank u!! :D

Comment: Hello How can I run this on windows10 home commands?

Answer (score 1):

I've always had success with the the log file permissions as 644.  When this has happened to me, more than once I might add, it has always been answered by the question linked below.  Since this is the first answer in Google for the query I use, I'm linking to the answer that I really want.

[Rails: Unable to access log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632592/rails-unable-to-access-log-file)