# Rails Error: Unable to access log file on aws lambda

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to run the Rails app in AWS lambda (using lamby gem) via docker image.
I'm getting the following error.

> Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /fi-service/log/development.log exists and is writable (ie, make it writable for user and group: chmod 0664 /fi-service/log/development.log). The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.

I even added the following commands in the dockerfile (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20319355/rails-error-unable-to-access-log-file-please-ensure-that-home-log-developm))

```
RUN touch log/development.log
RUN chmod 0664 log/development.log
```

Comment: think you need chmod `0666`

Comment: @dbugger I have tried that also.
It's not working

Comment: @AjithManiVeeramani any luck here? I am facing the same problem.